# Angular Observable data to csv

Tags: angular, observable

How can you generate a CSV file from a observable

```
download() {
  //const replacer = (key, value) => value === null ? '' : value;
  const header = 'Name;age;FavouriteFruit';
  const csv = this.persons$; 
  // How can I can I map the Observable data to csv lines.
  // This wil be an array of persons with the the properties age name and an array of 
  //fruits (string[])
  
  csv.unshift(header.join(',');
  const csvArray = csv.join('\r\n');

  const a = document.createElement('a');
  const blob = new blob([csvArray], { type: 'text/csv' });
  const url window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  a.href = url;
  a.download = 'fruit.csv';
  a.click();
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  a.remove()
}
```

First of all I think I have to subscribe to the Observable and map the data but I am a little bit confused how I must map it to a csv format

data I receive when I log Persons$:
[
{
"name": "Babulaas",
"Age": "88",
"FavouriteFruits": [
{
"name": "banana",
"description": "happy yello fruit"
}
]
}
]

Comment: share the data please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you indeed need to subscribe to the Observable to access its data, then transform that data into the CSV format.

```
    download() {
  // Header of the CSV file
  const header = 'Name,Age,FavouriteFruit';
  
  // Subscribe to the Observable
  this.persons$.subscribe(persons => {
    // Map the data to CSV format
    const csvContent = persons.map(person => {
      // If you need to check null and join the fruits array into a string. Otherwise ignore this line of code.
      const fruits = person.favouriteFruit && person.favouriteFruit.length > 0 ? person.favouriteFruit.join(';') : '';
      return `${person.name},${person.age},${fruits}`;
    });

    // Combine the header and the content
    csvContent.unshift(header);
    const csvArray = csvContent.join('\r\n');

    // Create a Blob from the CSV String
    const blob = new Blob([csvArray], { type: 'text/csv' });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    // Create an anchor element and trigger the download
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'persons.csv';
    a.click();

    // Cleanup
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    a.remove();
  });
}
```

This is just an example of what such a method could look like. I don't know the name of your observable or what structure it has. I'm basing this on the description in your example, but I doubt I'll hit exactly your structure, and many things can differ.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for the most part. how do render the name of the fruit. now it will render [object, object] which is correct because you don't specified the property. Can you use pluck or something else to filter only the name of the fruit in stead of the whole object as [object, object]

Comment: This works for me: const pluckroles = person.favouriteFruit.map(f => f['name']);